# Should I add the dll of my third libraries in the version control repository?

Tags: version-control, dll, mercurial, dvcs, nuget

Version control Best practices.
When developing a program, I use third party libraries, NUnit and others.
I want to share the sources of this program hosted on http://www.codeplex.com/ or http://code.google.com/hosting/.

What are good practices as regards third libraries?
Should I add the dll of my third libraries in the version control ?

Thank you,

Comment: I fear there are no single correct answers to this question. Would it be more suited on http://programmers.stackexchange?

Answer (score 3):

With the introduction of [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) you have a different way to do this.

See [this post by David Ebbo: Using NuGet without committing packages](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/03/using-nuget-without-committing-packages.html).

Basically you use NuGet to download and add package references to the libraries you want (assuming there's NuGet packages for the libraries you need), but do not add the Packages folder to your repository.

Instead you modify your pre-build step of the projects that require packages so that they automatically download the packages required if they're not present.

Testing has shown that this adds a minor delay to the build process when checking if the libraries are present, so this may or may not be good enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

We always do especially if we are linking against a specific version, we have an NUnit folder for example and then a version folder within it.